# Flattening array column and creating Index column for array elements at the same time -- Azure Data Factory

Tags: indexing, azure-data-factory, flatten

I have a dataset that in simple representation looks like:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [A,B] |
| 2 | [C] |

I want to denormalize the data and create another column while flattening, which would be the index of the elements in the array. The desired result set would look like:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 2 | C | 1 |

I was able to achieve the requirement using mapindex, keyvalues and mapassociation expression functions.
Somehow I feel like this is not the right way to do it and there must be a better and easier way to do it. I read the microsoft documentation and couldnt find it.

Can someone help/guide me to a better solution?

Edit 1:
Source is Azure Blob Storage. I have access to only ADF. Data is a complex XML document. All transformations are to be performed only with ADF.

Edit 2:
Target is SAP BW . But I don't have control on it. I can only write to it.

Comment: What's your source for the dataset?  Do you have access to a SQL database, Databricks cluster, Synapse Spark Pool or Mapping Data Flows?  Any of these could do this but it kind of depends on where it's coming from, what compute you have access to already I think.

Comment: Thanks for the help..Source is Azure blob storage and all computation is through adf

Comment: And what is the target?

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with the ADF Flatten transformation in data flows. Pick the Col2 array in the unroll property in Flatten.

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT Thanks for the suggestion. That will flatten the array to different records but is there a way to create index for the array elements as a different column while flattening?

Comment: @wBob target is SAP BW. I don't have much control on it. I can write to it that's all

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatten` transformation to flatten the array values and `Window` transformation to get the **RowNumber**, partition by Col1.

[Flatten transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten): Unroll by array column (Col2).

[image]

[Window transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-window): Connect the output of flatten to Windows transformation.

- Set a partition column in the **Over** clause.
- Set a sort column to **sort** the data ordering.
- In **window** **columns** setting, you can define the aggregation `rowNumber()` to get the index value based on col1.

[image]

**Output of Window transformation:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Niharika This is a solution that works. For me doing a window operation is costly considering the data size. I was looking for something like in pandas where we can generate the index column while doing the flatten transformation.